# MVC - trouble linking to another Controller/Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a view in what i'll call ControllerA from which i want to href/link to a view in another controller (ControllerB) and have that view (ViewB) come up in another browser tab. i tried the obvious method..

From ViewA..

```
<a href="/ControllerB/ActionB" target="_blank">SomeText</a>
```

ActionB does the usual return View();

the problem is when i click on the link, a new tab is opened but i get this error..

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ControllerB/ActionB

don't get it. i can 100% guarantee that that controller exists in the Controllers/ControllerB directory in the project.

and yes i did try this as well..

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionB", "ControllerB")" target="_blank">SomeText</a>
```

but same problem.

what did (sort of) work though was setting up the href in ViewA to call a jscript function (href="javascript:function()"). that function uses a jquery ajax call to jump into ControllerB (using the same url as above) and this actually works (it stops on the return View() in the debugger). the problem is, nothing else happens. no new tab is opened and the view doesn't appear anywhere.

how can i do this/what am i doing wrong?

**edit:** also tried this with the same result..

```
@Html.ActionLink("SignalR", "SRStart", "SignalR", null, new { target = "_blank" })
```

something to do with routing maybe?

**edit #2:**
i've seen this version of the error before. depending on how i set up the url, i'll get a more detailed 404 error the details of which include this..

> Requested URL    http:// localhost:64528 /Home /~ /SignalR /SRStart

notice that the Home controller (or directory - not sure) is appended by default to the front of the url i specify which is what is causing the error. not sure why this is happening other than the fact the view that contains the link is off the Home controller (ControllerA) but it's happening and it's a pain the butt.
so i guess the question now is - how do i prevent the current controller (Home) from being appended to the front of the url? some application setting somewhere?

Comment: May be obvious, but have you suffixed ControllerB with 'Controller'?
eg public class ControllerBController : Controller {

Comment: Yes, i did that. to be clearer, ControllerBs actual name is SignalRController and the action is SRStart. i used '/SignalR/SRStart' in the ActionLink which is correct i believe.

Comment: Can you post your controller code please?

Comment: just a standard return View(); but it never executes because it can't find the controller.

Comment: Without seeing your route config or controller it's difficult to determine. Views are just views, they don't really care where they came from as long as the model being fed to them is the right type. It looks like there is a problem with your routing. What happens when you have a [HttpGet] decorating the actionresult?  Also if there is an attribute there, is it system.web.mvc or system.web.http ?

Comment: If you type http:// localhost:64528/SignalR /SRStart in your browser, are you able to go to that route?

Comment: [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult SRStart()
  {
   return View();
  }
this works by typing the right path into the browser but there's still a pathing issue that occurs when clicking on the link from ControllerA's view. (read latest edit)

Comment: John - if by attributes you mean the usings at the top of the page i have system.web.mvc. i tried system.web.http but intellisense didn't show it. may be missing a reference to it. which one should i have?

Answer (score 1):

well this is interesting. when i posted my action method, i had just changed the attribute from [HttpPost] to [HttpGet] not thinking it would make any difference because of the pathing issue but then i ran it again and it worked. not going to pretend i understand why Home was appended to the url when i had Post as the attribute but guess it doesn't matter. so it was the attribute attached to the action method. interesting. thanx all..