# Call to MapSignalR causes Protocol error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

this is a follow-up to my previous question here..

[MVC - trouble linking to another Controller/Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423186/mvc-trouble-linking-to-another-controller-action)

as you can see, i eventually did get my view from another controller to display in a new tab so it was working. that is until i installed SignalR. the simple version using this tutorial as a guide..

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

the tutorial worked fine after following the steps to create a project. the only thing i had to do to make it work was change the version of the jquery signalr javascript file to the latest (it was one i didn't have because the tutorial was written in older VS 2012).

in any case, after following the same steps for my site, i now get an error when i click the link for /SignalR/SRStart (new tab)..

Protocol error: Unknown transport

playing around i found that this only happens after calling app.MapSignalR() in the startup.cs file. can't understand why since the tutorial i followed worked fine unless it has something to do with crossing over into another controller on that link. it's in the SRStart view that i placed all the signalr connection code and callback function but i don't think it's ever reached since the page doesn't even load.

this is my code..

startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

hub

```
public class SRHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        var conn = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SRHub>();
        conn.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(message);
        //Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(message);
    }
}
```

javascript in SRStart.cshtml

```
    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var conn = $.connection.sRHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        conn.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (message) {
            if (!message.contains('[EOF]')) {
                populateStreamDialog(message);
            }
        };

        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () {

            });
    });
```

any help would be appreciated..

Comment: What is route configuration for SRStart controller\view?

Comment: don't have one which is probably the problem. being still a bit new to MVC i didn't know enough to add one. could you give me some details on that plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate error. Problem is that `/SignalR` is route used by SignalR itself. 
By using MVC controller named `SignalRController` there is now conflict between SignalR and MVC causing the error.
Just rename you MVC controller `SignalRController` (and folder containing its views) to something else...

Comment: my God, was that it? sheesh. i never would have thought of that. thx much.

Comment: Pls make sure to accept the answer (not just up vote): _To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green_